# como crear una promesa y al ser success llamar a una variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promesas

Lo que tengo que hacer es que "loadCategoriesFilter" en el arranque de la pagina me tiene que dar una promise y cuando la promise es success llamar a "categoriesFilterCombo".

Lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
//Arranque de la pagina 

 if (!emptyProducts) {

        loadCategoriesFilter();
        loadStockFilter();

        var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);

        if(categoryId !== null) {
            applyFilter({page: 1}, {category: categoryId});        
        } else {
            applyFilter();
        }
    }
```

Mi funcion en categoriesFilterCombo:

```
var categoriesFilterCombo = function () {

        var combo = $('#categoriesFilter');
            combo.attr('#categoriesFilter', false);
            combo.find('option.').attr('#categoriesFilter', '#categoriesFilter');
            combo.trigger("liszt:updated");
            combo.trigger("change");
    };
```

Filtro por categorías + el fix por URL que me funcionaba

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
        categories = [];

    $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
         categories.push(element);
        });

        getParentCategories(categories);
        /*Fix load category filter by URL 
            $('#categoriesFilter').val(getParameterByName('categoryId',window.location.href));
            $('#categoriesFilter').trigger("liszt:updated");*/
        }
    }, 'json');
};
```

Aunque con ese fix ya realizaba lo que necesito, en realidad tengo que con estos datos crear la promise, y eso es lo que me hace falta.

Comment: No entiendo bien cuál es tu problema, ¿qué quieres hacer una vez hayas obtenido la respuesta? [Revisa la documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), puedes crear una petición y aplicarle `done, fail, always` o lo que necesites.

Comment: No se bien como crear correctamente la promises. entonces comparto los datos que tengo actualmente para poder ser orientado a crearla correctamente.

Comment: Es que la petición ya viene en forma de `Promise`, como dice la doc en el enlace anterior: *The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise* ([ver también aquí](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)) ... Lo que no se entiende es qué quieres hacer con los datos ¿? ¿quieres procesarlos en una función aparte o qué es lo que quieres?

Comment: Claro, tendria que crear una promise aparte con la variable loadCategoriesFilter, y cuando esta sea success, llamar a la variable categoriesFilterCombo. gracias por tu tiempo @A.Cedano

Comment: Que no que no, que Ajax te devuelve una `Promise`, ¿por qué dices que tienes que crear una `Promise`  aparte si ya es una `Promise`? Luego, puedes procesar los datos de la respuesta en `categoriesFilterCombo` si es lo que quieres. En la doc hay un ejemplo donde se usa `processData: false`, no sé si es eso lo que te interesa ¿?

Comment: te doy algunos datos para ver si puedo ser mas claro. Tiene que ser en JS la promise, no jquery y tengo que crear una promises porque , aunque con el fix load que puse en el filtro por categorias, yame realiza lo que necesito, hace que le pegue dos veces al servidor y tengo que aprovechar en el arranque de la pagina para que cargue solo una vez. Entonces eso es lo que tengo de codigo pero se puede desarmar para crear lo que te comento por mas de que esté funcionando.

Comment: Bueno, eso debería quedar claro en la pregunta. Tú estás mostrando código jQuery y se interpreta que quieres una solución basada en jQuery. No obstante, tu último comentario hace pensar que quieres una solución en JS puro. Ene se caso, [revisa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5587982) donde hay varios ejemplos de peticiones Ajax hechas en JS puro usando promesas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

Al cargar la pagina.

```
if (!emptyProducts) {

        loadCategoriesFilter();
        loadStockFilter();

        var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);
        var params = {};
        var filter = {};      

        if(categoryId !== null) {
            params.page = 1;
            filter.category = categoryId;
        } 

        applyFilter(params, filter);
    }
```

Los cambios en el que era categoriesFilterCombo:

```
var categoryId = getParameterByName('categoryId', window.location.href);

var applyFilterCategory = function () {
    $('#categoriesFilter').val(categoryId);
    $('#categoriesFilter').trigger("liszt:updated");

};
```

y los cambios en LoadcategoriesFilter:

```
var loadCategoriesFilter = function() {
    var url = '/stock/ajaxGetCategoriesTree/';

    $.post(url, function(response) {
        if (response.success) {
            categories = [];
            $.each(response.categoryTree, function(index, element){
            categories.push(element);
            });
            getParentCategories(categories);            
        }
    }, 'json').done(function() {
        applyFilterCategory();
    });
};
```